# Little question about a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

First, I apologize if my mathematic vocabulary might be unspecific, but I didn't study mathematics in English. So, I wondered if someone could help me solving this equation for $z \in \mathbb{C}$:
$$
z + |z|^2 = 0
$$
I'm sure the answer is easy but I can't figure it out... (always find $S\{-1;0\}$...)

Thanks!

Comment: Lest we forget, first we mention the solution $z=0$. Now we look for non-zero solutions. If $z=-|z|^2$, then taking norms we get $|z|=|z|^2$, so since $z\ne 0$ we have $|z|=1$. Thus $z=-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|z|^2 = z \bar z$, the equation factorizes as $z(1+\bar z) = 0$, from which it is immediately clear that $z=0$ and $\bar z = -1$ (i.e. $z=-1$) are solutions and that these are the only ones.

Answer (score 1):

Write $z=a+ib,$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then the equation becomes
$$(a+ib)+(a+ib)(a-ib)=0\iff a+ib+a^2+b^2=0\iff(a+a^2+b^2)=0\text{ and }(b=0),$$ which leads to study the other equation $$a+a^2=0\iff a\cdot(a+1)=0\iff (a=0)\text{ or }(a=-1)$$ and as you said you finally get $S=\{-1,0\}.$

Answer (score 1):

From $z=0-|z|^2$ it follows that $z\in{\mathbb R}$, but then $|z|^2=z^2$. It follows that $0=z+z^2=z(z+1)$, hence $z\in\{-1,0\}$. It is easily checked that these two numbers fulfill the given equation. (Note that this check is necessary since we do not have a general theory that guarantees at least two solutions for this type of equations.)